# Put shared axis labels to upper plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiple-axes

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
fig.show()
```

Returns this figure:

[image: Current]

But I want the x-axis labels below the first plot, not the second, like shown below. How can I achieve this?

[image: Desired]

Comment: set the labels by hand?

Comment: Mainly the position of the axis. Labelling itself is `xticks` I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @r-beginners brought me to a solution that also works when using the `plt.subplots` shortcut instead of instantiating each axis separately.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
plt.tick_params('x', labelbottom=False, labeltop=True)
fig.show()
```

he essential part is [`plt.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params.html) which take keyword arguments `labeltop` or `labelbottom` (as well as `labelleft` or `labelright` for shared axis on several columns) to select / deselect each axis individually.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/shared_axis_demo.html), so I answered it by referring to it: In the tick parameter, set the bottom label to false.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax0 = plt.subplot(211)
ax1 = plt.subplot(212, sharex=ax0, sharey=ax0)
#plt.plot([],[])
plt.tick_params('x', labelbottom=False)
#print(ax1.get_xticks())

plt.show()
```

[image]